# Error while executing the Install4j on photon OS

Tags: install4j

**Error Log:**

> Starting Installer ... Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xms32M -Xmx128M
>   This launcher was created with an evaluation version of install4j. An
>   error occurred: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Error log:
>   /tmp/install4jError4730936787587270008.log java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(GUIHelper.java:719)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:73)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.(ConsoleScreenExecutor.java:24)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.(InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.java:6)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Installer.java:87)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:56)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:45)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.start(UnixLauncher.java:66)
>           at install4j.Installer1845983829.main(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1349)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1324)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(GUIHelper.java:715)
>           ... 13 more **Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/OpenJDK-1.8.0.192/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so:
>   libharfbuzz.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or**
>   directory
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
>           at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:61)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
>           at sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(SunFontManager.java:339)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.font.SunFontManager.(SunFontManager.java:335)
>           at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:264)
>           at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1113)
>           at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1626)
>           at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateMetrics(WrappedPlainView.java:318)
>           at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateChildren(WrappedPlainView.java:297)
>           at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.insertUpdate(WrappedPlainView.java:463)
>           at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1610)
>           at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1869)
>           at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
>           at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
>           at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
>           at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
>           at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit.read(DefaultEditorKit.java:273)
>           at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setText(JEditorPane.java:1416)
>           at javax.swing.JEditorPane.(JEditorPane.java:290)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.createEditorPane(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:357)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.initFontManager(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:309)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.access$400(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:28)
>           at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor$2.run(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:77)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)**

**Java Version:**

root@photon-machine [ ~ ]# java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xms32M -Xmx128M
openjdk version "1.8.0-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-internal-_2018_10_24_06_54-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b00, mixed mode)

**OS Name:** VMware Photon/Linux

**Install4j version :** 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workarounds for font-related problems on headless machines are implemented in install4j 8.x, but not in install4j 6.x.

Comment: Thanks we will migrate to install4j8.x